# codeigniter redirection of URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

What is happening:-
 `testurl.com/index.php/controller/method` and `testurl.com/controller/method`, these both redirect to the same page that is index.php 
Requirement:- When somebody type `testurl.com/index.php/controller/method/` the url must be change to `testurl.com/controller/method` after loading the same page that is index.php

They are loading same page currently but the url is not getting change.

Codeigniter is new for me I know its very simple task, but I am blank at this point. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to remove index.php from the url

first : in config file  set `$config['index_page']` to blank i.e

`$config['index_page']=''`;

Second : place the .htacess file in the app root folder

`.htaccess` file content :-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|img|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

get more info here : - [Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

Comment: Its working fine but there is 1 problem that when I pass testurl.com/index.php/controller/ It redirect to testurl.com/index.php means If I pass the controller with index.php it redirect to the index page. However I wanted to redirect to view called by controller not at testurl.com/index.php

Comment: @NituDhaka this shouldn't be occur.this may be because of your server config.now you shouldn't use index.php in the url.

Comment: Yes I know it, I should not use index.php in url but this is the requirement that is why I  wanted to learn about rewrite rule can you please explain the above lines?

Comment: mentioned in doc : any HTTP request other than those for index.php, images, and robots.txt is treated as a request for your index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

To check if the guy is at the index.php-Version of your URL you test your base_url:

```
if(strpos(current_url(), "index.php") !== false)
```

(as in [1])

Then you can redirect him to base_url()/uri_string() with:

```
redirect(base_url().'/'.uri_string());
```

to see more play around with the url-helper.

[1] http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html